How to Make a Button Redirect to Employer Website Using URL from Custom Field?
I'm working on a WordPress project where I need a button to redirect users directly to an employer's website. The URL for the website is stored in a custom field called employer-website.
Here's the scenario:
The custom field employer-website contains the URL of the employer's website.
I want a button on the employer's profile page that, when clicked, takes the user to the URL specified in the employer-website custom field.
How can I achieve this functionality in WordPress?
Any help or guidance on how to implement this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
This is the button


when you say "employer's profile page" you mean a wordpress user profile, or a wordpress post / page?

wordpress user profile

Its been some time since I have used wordpress but I think you can do get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'custom-field-name', TRUE); , assign the value to a button then add an on click or wrap a buttn with an achor tag, etc.

check this question https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/114055

@Mr.Kenneth That was my first thought as well, although I'm not sure user profiles are handled as posts in Wordpress

possibly, get_userdata()? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_userdata

@GrafiCode did you atleast try it?

@Mr.Kenneth I'm not sure how OP handles custom fields. I for one use the PODS framework: it allows the creation of CTPs and custom fields, and also allows to EXTEND posts/pages / taxonomies / users to attach custom fields. Fact is, when I go to extend a feature, "POST / PAGES" and "USERS" are two different options, as if they were different entities. (if I extend USERS attaching custom fields, I can retrieve them from code using PODS apis) https://pods.io/

@GrafiCode that's why I asked if OP at least tried. It is hard to debug this since there is no code, just saying custom field.
